# How to fix "Stream is not generating quickly enough" error when the first song stream finishes?

Tags: node.js, youtube, youtube-api, discord, discord.js

I was making a discord.js bot and stumbled upon a problem with playing streams from youtube.

After the first stream finished playing dispatcher errors with "Stream is not generating quickly enough" and won't play any other streams until I restart the bot.

I'm using these modules:

- discord.js@11.4.0
- ffmpeg@0.0.4
- ffmped-binaries@3.2.2-3
- opusscript@0.0.6
- ytdl-core@0.25.0

I tried installing other versions of ytdl-core but that didn't help me.

Here's my code so far:

```
const yt = require("ytdl-core");

function play(bot, msg) {
  if (msg.guild.queue.songs.length < 1) {
    msg.guild.queue.playing = false;
    return msg.channel.send("Queue is empty");
  }

  if (!msg.guild.voiceConnection) {
    msg.member.voiceChannel.join().then(con => {
      let song = msg.guild.queue.songs.shift();
      msg.channel.send(`Playing: **${song.title}**!`);
      msg.guild.queue.playing = true;

      msg.guild.queue.dispatcher = con.playStream(yt(song.url))
        .on("end", reason => {
          console.log(reason);
          bot.queue[msg.guild.id].dispatcher.stop();
          setTimeout(play, 500, bot, msg);
        })
        .on("error", err => {
          console.log(err);
          bot.queue[msg.guild.id].dispatcher = null;
          setTimeout(play, 500, bot, msg);
        });
    });
  }
}

exports.run = async(bot, msg, args, ops) => {
  if (!msg.member.voiceChannel) return msg.channel.send("Connect to a voice channel first!");
  if (!args[0]) return msg.channel.send("Specify youtube url first!");
  yt.getInfo(args[0], (err, info) => {
    if (err) return msg.channel.send(err);
    if (!msg.guild.queue) {
      msg.guild.queue = {};
      msg.guild.queue.playing = false;
      msg.guild.queue.songs = [];
      msg.guild.queue.dispatcher = null;
    }
    msg.guild.queue.songs.push({
      url: info.video_url,
      title: info.title,
      requester: msg.author.username
    });
    if (msg.guild.queue.playing) {
      msg.channel.send(`Added **${info.title}** to queue list!`);
    } else {
      play(bot, msg);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Have you been able to check out this [github post](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/1225) regarding the error "Stream is not generating quickly enough"?

Comment: Sry but this is not my problem. The guy in the issue just turned the "bot michrophone" on, and after some people talked a bit, like turn on and off their mic's, then it errored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess easiest fix would be to use `discord.js master / v12-dev` wich can be installed by doing `npm i discordjs/discord.js` the master version has a full rewrite of the Voice Functions, wich of course has some breaking changes with it, but overall the issue with `stream is not generating fast enough` from ytdl is fixed in master.

Comment: Thank you, PLASMA chicken. But i need to add one last detail. For this to work you need to have ffmpeg-binaries@latest instead of @3.2.2-3 and then streams start to work perfectly. Though discord.js master syntax is a bit different from stable so i needed to figure this one out.